# Adding superscript to color2D.matplot rowname labels

Tags: r

I have been able to create a color2D.matplot, but I have trouble with putting the rownames labels the correct way. More specifically, how can I make the "+" symbol appear in superscript in labels CD4+, CD8+ and CD4+RTE in the plot? 
Here it is my code:

```
labels <- c("TREC",
        "KREC",
        "CD8+",
        "Plasmablast",      
        "CD4+RTE",
        "CD4+",
        "Tcells",
        "Lymphocyte")
labels1 <- paste(c("SNP1","SNP2"))
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)
require(grid)
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotrix)
mylwid = c(0.5,4)
mylhei = c(0.8,8.5)
par(mar=c(6,1,2,12),cex=1.8,mgp=c(3,0.3,0))
associations <- as.matrix(read.table(file = "heatmap.txt", header=FALSE, sep = "\t"))
cellcolors<-as.matrix(read.table(file ="heatmap_colors.txt", header=FALSE, sep = "\t"))
color2D.matplot(associations,cellcolors=cellcolors,xlab="", ylab="",axes=FALSE)
axis(1,las=2,labels=labels1,at=0.5:1.5,col.ticks='white')
axis(4,las=2,labels=labels, at=0.5:7.5,col.ticks='white')
legend.labels<-c("GW-significant","Suggestive","<0.05","<0.100","Non-significant","<0.100","<0.05","Suggestive","GW-significant")
color.legend(14.5,6,15.5,4,legend.labels,rect.col=c("#0000FF","#0066FF","#00CCFF","#CCFFFF","#FFFFFF","#FFFF00","#FFCC00","#FF6600","#FF0000"),align="rb",gradient="y",cex=1.6)
```